# Formalism of Non-abelian Gauge theory?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

Depending on the source I have seen two different definitions/formalisms for Non-abelian Gauge theories and was wondering how the two were related.

The first one is the more common where the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ is promoted to a matrix, which transforms like:
$$A_{a} \rightarrow UA_{a}U^{-1} +\frac{i}{g}U\partial_{a}(U^{-1}) $$

and the curvature tensor is written with an additional commutator $$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} -  ig[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}] $$

However in Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur I have seen the following definition for the above (specific for $SU(2)$)
The gauge field is a matrix that transforms like
$$\sigma \cdot W_{a} \rightarrow \sigma \cdot W_{a} + \frac{1}{g}\sigma\cdot\partial_{a}\alpha -\sigma\cdot\alpha \times W_{a} $$

Where $\alpha$ is phase rotation $U = e^{i\sigma\cdot\alpha/2}$ and $\sigma$ are the Pauli matrices.

Here the curvature tensor is defined as:

$$G_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}W_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}W_{\mu} - g(W_{\mu} \times W_{\nu}).$$

How are these two definitions related? I understand that the first is more general to all groups, but didn't know how to derive the second definition from this.

Comment: Show the reader the [exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) you worked out, and how you processed them.

Comment: For the SU(2) group they are the same thing in different notation.

Comment: @mikestone could use please explain how because it is not clear to me how to derive the  expressions for W and G from the general equations

Comment: I suggest comparing the SU(2) structure constants to the expression for the cross product of two 3-vectors written in index notation.

Answer (score 2):

The first notation hides the Lie algebra  generators by writing   $A_\mu = A_m^a {\boldsymbol \lambda_a}$ where the implied  generators obey
$$
[{\boldsymbol \lambda}_a, {\boldsymbol \lambda}_b]= i {f_{ab}}^c {\boldsymbol \lambda}_c.
$$
The second notation makes the generators  explicit and  writes
$$
{\bf A}_\mu\cdot  {\boldsymbol \lambda}.
$$

For SU(2), the generators are the Pauli matrices and  commutator algebra of the Pauli matrices tells us that
$$
[{\bf a}\cdot {\boldsymbol \sigma}, {\bf b}\cdot {\boldsymbol \sigma}]= 2i ({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\cdot {\boldsymbol \sigma} 
$$
and the rest should be straightforward.